# Define Startup Method in Dll according to the Command Line

Tags: c#, dll

I have a ShowUsers.dll with two method name ShowUserProfile & ShowProfileWithArea.

When the user enters cmd>ShowUsers.dll 'UserName' it should call ShowUserProfile

When the user enter cmd>ShowUsers.dll 'UserName' 'Area' it should call ShowProfileWithArea.

How I can configure it in the dll code to accomdate these calls from command line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dll` stands for "dynamic linked *library*", so basically doesn't have any startup method concept. If you want to make conditional execution of methods within that library there is no way then use other `exe` like a bridge and route the call to different method of `dll` based on paramater recieved within `exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make a console application in order to run it. I mean you need exe instead of dll.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 if (args.Length > 0)
 {
  if(args[0] == "your text")
     // call first method
  else 
     // call second method       
 }
}
```